# C#: Mongo DB nested array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB and the C# SDK.

I have this structure:

[image]

and the following code:

```
FilterDefinition<RoleEntry> subFilter = Builders<RoleEntry>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Sub, _sub);
FilterDefinition<RoleEntry> roleFilter = Builders<RoleEntry>.Filter.ElemMatch(p => p.Roles, r => r.DealerId != null);
FilterDefinition<RoleEntry> andFilter = Builders<RoleEntry>.Filter.And(subFilter, roleFilter);

UpdateDefinition<RoleEntry> updateDefinition = Builders<RoleEntry>.Update.PullAll("Roles.$.RoleIds", roleIds);
UpdateResult updateResult = await _mongoConnector.RoleEntryCollection.UpdateOneAsync(andFilter, updateDefinition, new UpdateOptions { }, cancellationToken);
```

`roleIds` is an Array of strings containing `PurchasingManager`.

**Problem**: The code only removes the first PurchasingManager, but I want to remove it in all entries of the "Roles" -> "RoleIds" arrays.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're using UpdateOneAsync. Have you tried with UpdateManyAsync?